# check mark repeating after some data added....when i make check

Tags: ios

i have one table view with left side check button. for first 6 data its working well. when i add three more data to my table view after that when i check my first data my 7 the data also getting check. like wise when i check one data some other data also repeatng with check mark.....
 i am using core data....if any one could answer this ......

```
  @interface ViewController ()
{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter;
}

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *notes;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize addButton;
@synthesize catefetchedResultsController;


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Notes";

    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;

             CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            [animation setDuration:2.0];
            [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];

        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];

        [[addButton layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToDown"];


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Notes"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.notes = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];

    NSSortDescriptor *titleSorter= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"mod_time" ascending:NO];

    [self.notes sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:titleSorter]]
    ;

    NSLog(@"Your Error - %@",error.description);

    [tableView reloadData];
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.notes.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //UIButton *testButton;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40)];


        [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oval"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell addSubview:testButton];
        [cell setIndentationLevel:1];
        [cell setIndentationWidth:45];





    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }


    // Configure the cell...
        NSManagedObject *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSDate *date = [note valueForKey:@"mod_time"];

        NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];


        cell.textLabel.text = [note valueForKey:@"title"];



        cell.detailTextLabel.text = dateString;




    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Avenir"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:19.0];


    cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:15.0];

}

-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender




{

        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

        if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oval"]])
        {

            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else
        {
            [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oval"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
    }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    AddNoteViewController *addNoteVC = [AddNoteViewController new];

    // to remove unused warning....
#pragma unused (addNoteVC)

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)cTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [self.notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i saw your code and yes the  issue is  reusability just  change  this  and it will solve your  problem

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//UIButton *testButton;

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40)];


    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oval"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:testButton];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:1];
    [cell setIndentationWidth:45];





cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;




// Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDate *date = [note valueForKey:@"mod_time"];

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];


    cell.textLabel.text = [note valueForKey:@"title"];



    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dateString;




return cell;

}
```

Comment: how to update my coredata filed ,i need to save my check mark too??

Answer (score 0):

As cells get reused, you have to prepare them for reuse, or your button will show the previous image when set by another row.

You have to reset the button's (selected) state to match its state for the current row.

You can do this either in tableView:cellForRowAtIbdexPath: or the cell's prepareForReuse method.

**Update:**

The preferred way to do this is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a UIButton property.  This is much better than adding a button to the cell's (contentView, not) view.

In your custom cell, it would look like:

```
@interface ButtonCell : UITableViewCell
{
    @property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton *toggleButton;
}
```

You can then hookup IBOutlets and IBActions between your storyboard custom cell at its ButtonCell class.

Then it's a simple matter to access the button in your cell by property:

```
[cell.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oval"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

If each row is supposed to start with that default state where the image is an oval, you would make sure to call those lines from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

This overwrites any previous toggle state left over from the other row the cell had been used for, so you won't see a tick when you expect an oval :)

**Update 2:**

Since you have a custom cell you've subclassed that already has a button on it, you no longer have to create or add a button to the cell's (content) view.  So, this code from your old approach no longer applies:

```
    [cell addSubview:toogleButton]; // <-- remove this
```

Next, a `UITableViewCell` doesn't have a toggleButton property.  You need to use your subclassed ButtonCell, which *does* have a toggleButton property.  Dequeue a custom cell (which you've specified and hooked up in the storyboard's dynamic prototype cell).

```
    ButtonCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Since that method always returns a cell, you can eliminate all the `cell == nil` conditional code.

Now that you have a custom cell, you set its image.

Since `cellForIndexPath` is not the place where you toggle its state, you don't want any conditional code there to change it between an oval and a tick.

Your present approach is trying to make the button keep track of its own ticked/oval state, by changing the image it displays.  **But the cell's button will be reused as cells scroll off the screen.  This means the button can't keep track of whether its previous row was ticked or not.**

Whenever you need to remember things like whether a row is ticked or not, you want to keep track of this in (an array in) the model.

So, conditionally set your custom button's image, based on the model.

```
    if ([self.noteState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) // An array of flags indicating whether a row is checked or not
    {
        [cell.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oval"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
```

Now your table rows will appropriately be checked off or not.

Since your model has checked state, you would also modernize your `buttonTouched` code to similarly update the model and toggle the button.

I leave that as an exercise for you.  If you've understood everything else up to this point, you won't have any problem applying what you've learned.

Your goal should be to learn and understand what a block of code is meant to do, instead of simply copying and pasting it from StackOverflow.

I appreciate that you want to fix problems with the app you're developing but unless you understand how or why something works, you'll struggle with trying to fix someone else's code.

If you have specific questions, please ask in the comments, and I'll try to answer them!

Comment: can i have some example plz?

Comment: I've added an example.  If you are learning this, it's good to go through some of Apple's tutorials that explains how to use custom cells, and deal with cell reuse.  tableViews aren't too complex, but you will appreciate learning how to properly code common examples like this :)

Comment: I've looked at your new code.  Hopefully the additional explanation will clarify things.  Please add a comment if you have any questions about this approach!